# How to convert json file to excel/sql query

Tags: oracle, hadoop, impala

I have an ETL process where supplemental/delta load is generated by source system vendor team in a json file and given to Dev team to load in table. And source system has agreed to provide the testing team with excel spreadsheet with changes/updates to data. Is there a way where Json file can be converted to Excel using some code/macro. There is no indicator or date field to track changes in the table loaded. SO inputs are excel sheet and json file. Since it is a regulated industry, using online converters is not recommended. Any ideas on how to do this, or better any other other approach for testing data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way where Json file can be converted to Excel using some code/macro

Maybe, but asking for such "libraries" is off topic here.

You've listed Hadoop in your tags, so you are welcome to drop JSON into HDFS, load a table schema over it in Hive (or Impala) using JSONSerde.

Then you can render the data into Excel using an ODBC connector for Hive (or Impala)